# R script is locked - can't edit it

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R, so I have probably done a newbie-fail. I can not write anything in my different scripts. The only thing I can, is to write directly to the console. Can someone please help? I have some task that has to be done soon, so every help would be appreciated.

I am only allowed to write when I make a new script....

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: Its hard to answer this question without seeing what you're seeing. Can you post a screenshot of what it is you are trying to edit?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a hurry:

Copy all your files to a new folder and work with them there. It should take case of most problems like this.